# Label.Text not updating in the browser when I set it in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

Label text not updating after handling gridview row update.

My devexpress gridview has a row updating handler that when I try to change the text on a label, that change is not reflected on the screen.
I am not getting any error either.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web" TagPrefix="dxwgv" %>
```

df

```
 <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="aspxgrdNotes" KeyFieldName="PoolItemNoteId" ClientInstanceName="grdNotes" OnRowUpdating="aspxgrdNotes_RowUpdating"
                        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowsCache="false">                    
                        <SettingsCommandButton>
                            <EditButton ButtonType="Image" Text="Edit" Image-IconID="edit_edit_16x16" />
                        </SettingsCommandButton>
                        <Columns>
                            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Id" FieldName="PoolItemNoteId" VisibleIndex="0" ReadOnly="true" CellStyle-Wrap="True" Width="100px" Visible="false"/>
                            <dxe:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="3" ShowEditButton="true" Caption="Edit"/>
                            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Date" FieldName="NoteDate" VisibleIndex="2" ToolTip="Created Date"
                                ReadOnly="true" Width="100px">
                                <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" EncodeHtml="False">
                                </PropertiesTextEdit>
                            </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Note" FieldName="NoteText" VisibleIndex="2"
                                ReadOnly="false" CellStyle-Wrap="True" Width="600px">
                            </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>                        
                        </Columns>
                        <SettingsPager PageSize="25" ShowDefaultImages="False" Position="TopAndBottom">
                            <AllButton Text="All" />
                            <NextPageButton Text="Next &gt;" />
                            <PrevPageButton Text="&lt; Prev" />
                        </SettingsPager>                    
                        <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" ShowGroupPanel="True" />
                        <SettingsBehavior AllowMultiSelection="false" AllowGroup="true" />                    
                        <SettingsPager PageSize="25" ShowDefaultImages="False">
                            <AllButton Visible="true" Text="All" />
                            <FirstPageButton Visible="true" />
                            <LastPageButton Visible="true" />
                            <NextPageButton Text="Next &gt;">
                            </NextPageButton>
                            <PrevPageButton Text="&lt; Prev">
                            </PrevPageButton>
                        </SettingsPager>
                        <Templates>
                            <EmptyDataRow>
                                No notes entered for this pool item.
                            </EmptyDataRow>                        
                        </Templates>                    
                    </dxwgv:ASPxGridView>

                    <dxwgv:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblErrMsg" Text="" ForeColor="DarkRed" Visible="false"></dxwgv:ASPxLabel>
```

code behind:

```
Protected Sub aspxgrdNotes_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs) Handles aspxgrdNotes.RowUpdating
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.aspxgrdNotes.CancelEdit()
    ' Update note
    Dim poolItemNote As New PoolItemNote
    If poolItemNote.LoadByPrimaryKey(e.Keys("PoolItemNoteId")) Then
        poolItemNote.NoteText = e.NewValues("NoteText")
        poolItemNote.ModBy = ALGMembershipUser.UserName
        poolItemNote.ModTime = DateTime.Now
        poolItemNote.Save()
        ' Rebind the notes grid
        BindJobDetailData()
    Else
        lblErrMsg.Text = "Error updating note.  Try reloading the page."
        lblErrMsg.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting the `EnableCallBacks` property of the `ASPxGridView` to `false`